# Is it possible in AHK to find out what the result of a certain key combination would be?

Tags: if-statement, variables, autohotkey

Here is an example. I basically want to check if pressing shift and 1 is equal to ! (which is the case on the english keyboard)

```
x = +1
if (x = !) {
  Send abc
}
```

The above code is wrong of course but is it possible to do something like this?

**EDIT:**

I just want to check in which language settings I am, because one part of the script should only be enabled when I am using the the Japanese keyboard and one part only when I am using the English or the German one.

For example if pressing "a" displays "a", then I am on the English or German keyboard and if pressing "a" displays "あ", then I am on the Japanese one.

Comment: Only indirectly. The way will depend on the context in which it will be used. For what purpose do you need it?

Comment: I just want to check in which language settings I am, because one part of the script should only be enabled when I am using the the Japanese keyboard and one part only when I am using the German one. For example if pressing "a" displays "a", then I am on the English or German keyboard and if pressing "a" displays "あ", then I am on the Japanese one.